# Response throwing error: Server Did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am trying to test a soap url. But I am getting the error response as mentioned in the question everytime I send the soap request. My code is as shown:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

        MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage sm = mf.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = sm.getSOAPPart();

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

        SOAPHeader sh = sm.getSOAPHeader();
        SOAPBody sb = sm.getSOAPBody();
        sh.detachNode();
        QName postageLabelXML = new QName("www.envmgr.com/LabelService", "GetPostageLabelXML");

        SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = sb.addBodyElement(postageLabelXML);
        QName qn = new QName("LabelRequestXML");
        SOAPElement quotation = bodyElement.addChildElement(qn);
        QName qnLabelRequest = new QName("LabelRequest");
        SOAPElement qnLabelRequestQuotation = quotation.addChildElement(qnLabelRequest);

        MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = sm.getMimeHeaders();
        mimeHeaders.addHeader("Host", "https://elstestserver.endicia.com");
        mimeHeaders.addHeader("Content-Length", "65536");
        mimeHeaders.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        mimeHeaders.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.envmgr.com/LabelService/GetPostageLabelXML");

        System.out.println("\n Soap Request:\n");
        sm.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        URL endpoint = new URL("https://elstestserver.endicia.com/LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx");
        SOAPMessage response = connection.call(sm, endpoint);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.writeTo(out);
        String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(response.getContentDescription());
        System.out.println("xml -= " + strMsg);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code produces the following xml as request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <GetPostageLabelXML xmlns="www.envmgr.com/LabelService">
         <LabelRequestXML>
            <LabelRequest />
         </LabelRequestXML>
      </GetPostageLabelXML>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The required xml is :

```
POST /LabelService/EwsLabelService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: elstestserver.endicia.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "www.envmgr.com/LabelService/GetPostageLabelXML"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetPostageLabelXML xmlns="www.envmgr.com/LabelService">
      <LabelRequestXML>
         <LabelRequest>...some xml </LabelRequest>
      </LabelRequestXML>
    </GetPostageLabelXML>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

After spending around 2 hours now in this issue I am not able to guess the real issue behind this error response :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap:Body>
          <soap:Fault>
              <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
              <faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: .</faultstring>
             <detail />
          </soap:Fault>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Please let me know if any error is noticed in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding an additional 'http://' in my

```
mimeHeaders.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.envmgr.com/LabelService/GetPostageLabelXML");
```

It worked fine when I removed the http:// suffix. So the changed line was

```
mimeHeaders.addHeader("SOAPAction", "www.envmgr.com/LabelService/GetPostageLabelXML");
```